# fulltext and INT columns integer the same query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, indexing

I have a fulltext index on column `Title`. But the query contains additional "AND" condition where an integer column "CategoryID" with index is involved.

What is the best solution for this situation? This query just use fulltext index but I want this query to use fulltext + integert column index

```
SELECT * 
FROM News 
WHERE MATCH(Title) AGAINST('value')  
  AND CategoryID=1
```

Comment: There are a few reasons, copy paste the output of `explain select * 
FROM News 
WHERE MATCH(Title) AGAINST('value')  
  AND CategoryID=1` in the question.

Comment: If more than 30-40% of all rows involved have `categoryID=1`, then MySQL will never use an index. This is called low cardinality. When selecting a large percentage of rows it's faster not to use an index.